# Symfony2: Get roles of groups in user entity but avoid query inside entity

Tags: performance, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, scalability

My `User` entity implements `UserInterface` and therefore provides the `getRoles()` method. In my system a `User` can belong to multiple `Group`s. A group can have multiple roles. Thus a user's roles can be determined by collecting all groups and merging the lists of those groups' roles. The same thing is possible with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).

The easiest algorithm would be:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }
    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

I think this solution is problematic because it will scale badly. For each group a new query has to be executed, so the amount of queries depends on the amount of groups.

Usually I'd solve this by defining a single query which collects all groups of the user and joins the groups' roles. That would require calling the `UserRepository` (or directly building a Doctrine query) from the `User` entity and I believe that is a bad practice.

So how could I avoid this bad practice while maintaining the performance advantages of a single join query?

(This time it was very hard for me to find a question title that fits. I'm not sure whether there are other simililar situations but I don't think so, because usually I would provide such method in the repository itself. In this case the `UserInterface` requires it to be in the entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom UserProvider.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider for the documentations.

Inside this user provider you have to make your query to select the user from an username and add a join to the group entity, so you only have one query